# Mapping URLs in my handler script in App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url, mapping

I have

```
class Auth(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self,username,password):
        self.response.out.write("auth" + self.request.get("username"))
```

The structure of my URL will be:

```
/api/auth/?username=xxxx&password=xxxx
```

How do I map this URL in my handler script?

Comment: Any chance you can use a POST instead?  Passwords in GETs are not best practice.  (Extra credit: use something better than plain passwords across the wire)

Answer (score 4):

**Handler:**

```
class Auth(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("username" + self.request.get("username"))
        self.response.out.write("password" + self.request.get("password"))
```

**Url:**

```
/api/auth?username=xxxx&password=xxxx
```

**Application:**

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/api/auth', Auth),
    ], debug=True)
```

Comment: Not sure why yours didn't work but I got this to work (/api/auth/(.*)(.*)',Auth)

Comment: @jwesonga That only works because `(.*)` matches the empty string, and you have two additional parameters 'username' and 'password'. Remove those parameters from your handler - you have to use `self.request.get` to get the query string arguments.